# How do I make Eclipse to not indent comments?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

I like how Eclipse IDE indents my source code but I would like to keep my comments intact. How do I make Eclipse not touch comments in Java source code?

I am using Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Formatter` here you have to create a copy of the default rules and change then as you like. Have a look at the `Comments` tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, Goto Window->Preferences->Java->Formatter and click on Edit your active profile.
In the Comments tab, you will have the options to achieve what you want with a preview. Hope this helps

(Note: You may want to duplicate the existing profile if you need to revert back)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom formatting rules in eclipse. Go to Eclipse `Preferences--> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter` and add your rules.